# Given $a>0$, $\frac{1}{x^2+a^2}$ is not a Schwarz function.

Tags: fourier-series, fourier-transform, schwartz-space

Given $a>0$,  $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2+a^2}$ is not a Schwarz function.

Please verify if this is correct:

Although Poisson Sumation formula is working for this function $f$, I think it is not Schwarz, since $f’(x)=-2x(x^2+a^2)^{-2}$, and $\lim_{x \to \infty} |-2x^5(x^2+a^2)^{-2}| = \infty$, so for $\alpha = 4$ and $\beta = 1$ there cannot exist $C_{\alpha,\beta}$ such that $|x^{\alpha}f^{(\beta)}(x)|\leq C_{\alpha,\beta}$.

Also, in Schwarz space can it be taken $\alpha, \beta = 0$?

Comment: (my derivative was wrong. fixed.)

Comment: One (necessary but not sufficient) condition for a function to be a Schwarz function is that $\forall n \in \mathbb N, \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} x^n f(x) = 0$.

Comment: this answers both of my questions, right? it is not schwarz and I can take $\alpha,\beta=0$ in schwarz definition.

Comment: It is indeed not Schwarz, but the Schwarz definition must hold for **all** $\alpha, \beta$, not just one couple.

Comment: oh, yes, I expressed myself poorly. I mean that it must hold for $\alpha,\beta \geq 0$ instead of $\alpha,\beta >0$ as I previously thought.

Comment: Yeah, both being 0 is also included in the set of all $\alpha, \beta$ indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Schwartz space* on $\mathbb{R}$ is the set of all smooth functions $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that for all nonnegative integers $\alpha$ and $\beta$, the function $x\mapsto x^{\alpha}f^{(\beta)}(x)$ is bounded.

**Hint**: In your case, take $\alpha=3$ and $\beta=0$ to get
$$
x^{3}f^{(0)}(x)=\frac{x^{3}}{x^{2}+a^{2}}.
$$
What can you say about the above as $|x|\rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: goes to $\infty$ for $x\to \infty$ and to $-\infty$ for $x \to -\infty$, then it´s not bounded.